Error when I try to install some npm or expo packages
I'm having a error when I try to install some packages from npm or npx.
This error happens on more than one machine, so I think I'm not the one that is facing this.
I created an app with expo (npx create-expo-app -t) as I do every-day, then I re-instaled the dependencies with npm i. It works fine, but when I try to install an package, like npm i native-base a strange error occurs. I tried to change the version and solve this with everything I know, and searched on web. Also, I tried in another computer and the same happened.
Node js v20.12.2
This is the error and the APP code:
Error:
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.6.0
2 info using node@v20.12.2
3 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc
4 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\tonym\OneDrive\Documentos\Lessons\react-native\testing-error\.npmrc
5 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\tonym\.npmrc
6 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
7 verbose title npm i native-base
8 verbose argv "i" "native-base"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-29T05_40_36_006Z-
10 verbose logfile C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-29T05_40_36_006Z-debug-0.log
11 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
12 silly logfile done cleaning log files
13 silly idealTree buildDeps
14 silly fetch manifest native-base@*
15 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/native-base 1081ms (cache revalidated)
16 silly fetch manifest @types/react@~18.2.45
17 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact 30ms (cache hit)
18 silly fetch manifest @types/react-native@*
19 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-native 1421ms (cache revalidated)
20 silly fetch manifest react@18.2.0
21 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 19ms (cache hit)
22 silly fetch manifest react-dom@*
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom 77ms (cache revalidated)
24 silly fetch manifest react@^18.3.1
25 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
25 verbose stack     at #failPeerConflict (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1386:25)
25 verbose stack     at #loadPeerSet (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1379:29)
25 verbose stack     at async #loadPeerSet (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1320:11)
25 verbose stack     at async #buildDepStep (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:923:11)
25 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:203:7)
25 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
25 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:154:5)
25 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:150:5)
25 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\entry.js:74:5)
26 verbose cwd C:\Users\tonym\OneDrive\Documentos\Lessons\react-native\testing-error
27 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
28 verbose node v20.12.2
29 verbose npm  v10.6.0
30 error code ERESOLVE
31 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
32 error
33 error While resolving: testing-error@1.0.0
33 error Found: react@18.2.0[2m[22m
33 error [2mnode_modules/react[22m
33 error   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
33 error   [95mpeer[39m react@"*" from native-base@3.4.28[2m[22m
33 error   [2mnode_modules/native-base[22m
33 error     native-base@"*" from the root project
33 error
33 error Could not resolve dependency:
33 error [95mpeer[39m react@"^18.3.1" from react-dom@18.3.1[2m[22m
33 error [2mnode_modules/react-dom[22m
33 error   [95mpeer[39m react-dom@"*" from native-base@3.4.28[2m[22m
33 error   [2mnode_modules/native-base[22m
33 error     native-base@"*" from the root project
33 error
33 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
33 error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
33 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
34 error
34 error
34 error For a full report see:
34 error C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-29T05_40_36_006Z-eresolve-report.txt
35 verbose exit 1
36 verbose code 1
37 silly unfinished npm timer reify 1714369236579
38 silly unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1714369236584
39 silly unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1714369237254
40 silly unfinished npm timer idealTree:#root 1714369237255
41 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\tonym\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-29T05_40_36_006Z-debug-0.log

package.json:
{
  "name": "testing-error",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

